# incompatible type jpa

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, h2

I'm using JPA, having an etity with column type :

```
@Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "bpchar(1)")
private String name;
```

I'm using PostgreSql as my database which supports bpchar type, now I'm trying to add H2 for my tests,
But the problem is that when I run the test I get this:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Type de données inconnu: "bpchar"
Unknown data type: "bpchar"; SQL statement:
```

is there an alternative to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just use a standard type like `varchar(1)` that works across all DBMS?

Comment: You can use a generic definition in the annotation like @Column(name="name", length=1) and if you don't like the generated type you can override in XML. You can then have one XML file for PostgreSQL and one for MySQL and one for H2 and... with only the special stuff.

Comment: Are you using Postgres compatibility mode in H2?

Comment: Have you tried using `Charachter`instead of `String`?

Comment: yes i'm using coplatibility mode @Kayaman

Comment: i think the problem is linked to the unsuported type of bpchar in H2 @DavideD'Alto

Comment: when i use the @Column(name="name", length=1), it throws another exception when i run the real DataBase, it says that DB expected a bpchar, and it found a Varchar (because of the String type) @ewramner

Comment: @Hamza did you override and specify bpchar in the JPA XML configuration? If not that was the idea. Generate the common stuff with annotations and override in XML where it is needed (and no more).

Comment: @ewramner can you give me some urls  to check how to do that

Comment: See https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/persisting_an_annotation_less_pojo for a simple example of XML mapping. See 12.2, page 512, for XML overriding rules in https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html.